# MySQL .MYD missing (errno: 144), anyway to repair/recover with .TMD ?

Tags: mysql

My Client Database has problem that said

> #1016 - Can't open file: 'i_am_error_table.MYI' (errno: 144)

after I try to repair, I notice that in mysql data, **i_am_error_table.MYD is missing**

currently, in mysql data, I found only i_am_error_table.MYI and i_am_error_table.TMD

I noticed that .TMD file size is similar to .MYD

So, is it anyway to recover .MYD with .TMD file? or is it has any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .TMD file is a "temporary data" file.  If you don't have a .MYD file, you can move the .TMD file into its place and it *might* work.  Far more reliable, though, is to restore the database from the latest backup and then rolling forward to the most recent recovery point with the binary logs that you're *definitely* keeping, because no professional sysadmin would be running a database without backups, right?

Comment: Yes, I will start handle their database on 20 September (currently, I'm undergoing on discussion things with their company), So, I still didn't have permission to get/make their backup yet. I will try your suggest first, Thanks !

Comment: It's work, by 1. renaming .TMD file to .MYD file, 2. restart mysql server once, 3. called REPAIR TABLE i_am_error_table